# MANIFEST file in Azure IoT Edge edgehub folder is increasing in size

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I can see one MANIFEST-000004 file in edgehub folder. Its increasing in size daily. What is this MANIFEST file and is there any way to reduce it? I am using edgeagent 1.0.10.4 and edgehub 1.0.10.4.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have deployed Azure Blob Storage on IoT Edge.

> Azure Blob Storage on IoT Edge provides a block blob and append blob storage solution at the edge. A blob storage module on your IoT Edge device behaves like an Azure blob service, except the blobs are stored locally on your IoT Edge device.

Ref: [Store data at the edge with Azure Blob Storage on IoT Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-store-data-blob?view=iotedge-2020-11)

In order to reduce the size of your blobs you need to Turn ON the deviceAutoDelete feature and then specify the time in minutes (deleteAfterMinutes) after which the blobs will be automatically deleted.